# Javascript Game for Kids

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I'm trying to make a game in javascript. I still have many issues in the code. The code is supposed to have 2 buttons; one for shuffling images dice and a button to check if the kid wrote the correct answer or not.

- 2 buttons
- 1 textbox
- and a place to show the answer if it's correct or not

Here is my code.

I don't know why when I put the source of document.getElementbyID("test") it shows nothing 
because I want every time I click on start a random image is selected.

I would appreciate any help as I am still a beginner in javascript.

```
  <head> 

<script type="text/javascript">


function startf(){
var images = []; 
index = 0;
images[0] = "<img src='1.png' length=70px width=75px>";
images[1] = "<img src='2.png' length=70px width=75px>";
images[2] = "<img src='3.png' length=70px width=75px>";
images[3] = "<img src='4.png' length=70px width=75px>";
index = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
take(index);

function take(ind)
{
return document.getElementbyId("ind")="What should i put here";
}
}
function check(){
var ch=getElementbyId("answer").value;
if (ch=index+1)
{
document.getElementbyId.innerHTML="TRUE";
}
else
{
document.getElementbyId.innerHTML="False";
}

}
</script><br>
</head>
<img id="test" src=""  alt="..." length="75px" width="75px" />

<body>

<input type="button" value="start" onclick="startf()">
<input id="answer" type="text" name="checkvalue" value="Enter Value" onclick="check()">
<div id="fa">
</div>
<input type="button" value=chek onclick="check()">


</body>
```

Comment: PUNCTUATION!...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please make sure you html is valid. There are a number of html errors. Also consider using http://jsfiddle.net to create an example that can be analysed easily. You'll receive a lot more help.

Comment: `getElementbyID` `ID` should be `Id`. You also have one using `by` which should be `By`. Consider using a better IDE.

Comment: Console says: `TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'getElementbyID'`. Stackoverflow is not a debugging service, you could do a little yourself.

Comment: i corrected the id but still the shuffling not working

Comment: It is good that you are trying to make something yourself, but prior to such an endeavor, you should obtain working knowledge of JavaScript. Plenty of tutorials and resources are available on the internet, make yourself familiar with the language first.

Comment: Run your javascript throughout http://jshint.com and your html through http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input and if you still have any problems come back here.

Comment: On a second glance, yes, there are many problems regarding JavaScript basics. I recommend to read the MDN JavaScript guide first: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide. For example, comparison is done with `==` or `===`, `=` is the assignment operator.

Answer (score 4):

1- Put and end to each instructions --> `;`

2- Do not use document.getElementById directly, there will be at least one occurence with an error into it and you don't want that.

```
function _e(id) {
   return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

3- Always put brackets and (...) around your IF-ELSE blocks:

```
if (...) {
    //....
} else {
    //....
}
```

4- Every tag attributes should have " " around their values, for example:

```
<input type="button" value="start" onclick="check()" />
```

5- You could only put image paths in your array since it seems to be what needs to be updated in #test image.

Comment: I know :-) but I think it's important stuff to care about before getting into bigger projects.

Comment: While it is good practice, having quotes around attribute values is not always *necessary*. In this case it's perfectly valid to omit them (assuming it's HTML and not XHTML).

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for pointing out, I edited to "should have"

Comment: thank you very much i reviewed all respones i fixed what everybody said but i didn't understand the point of using a function to call getElementbyId because i still can't make it right i just want it to show it at the top of the page what check my code after updating and correcting but plz tell me what should i correct in getElementbyId exactly because i'm still a beginner thanks

Comment: using a fonction to call getElementById is a custom trick to avoid spelling mistakes; in college most of problems in my class were caused by "docment.getElementById", "document.geteLement...", etc. so it became an habit for me to ensure that this won't happend, you are free to use it or not

Comment: can you plz just correct this part of the code for me because i don't know why is it still not working plz just this part

Comment: @user1928775: Well, some code you wrote does not make sense, and correcting every bit of code for you is not what SO is for. For example, what did you intend with this line: `return document.getElementbyId("ind")="What should i put here";`?  Apart from the spelling mistake, `getElementById` **returns a DOM element**, you cannot assign a string to it. I understand that you just started with JS, but in this case you should read some more tutorials first.

Comment: that's what i'm asking you i'm trying to make what you said call getElementById using a function - sorry that was Frederik - and i mentioned that in my previous comments just help me in the part of the getElementbyId just give me an idea no problem

Comment: @user1928775 You first need to understand how javascript works. I  think that the advice FelixKling gave you is the best one for this part. You won't learn a thing if you just get the final solution here.

Comment: @user1928775: Idea for what? `document.getElementById` will return the DOM element with the passed ID (if it exists). Then you can manipulate the node. What else do you want to know?

Answer (score 1):

It is `document.getElementById` check the casing. Your check function is wrong... you can't assign a value to document.getElementById function. Also your if is wrong. Do you know any JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing what you want is probably something like this. You seem to be trying to add or replace an element just by using `document.getElementById(id) = something` but that's not how it works. Instead, to change an image to another file you need to alter its `src` attribute. (There are other ways but this is maybe the simplest.)

```
// Declare the variable called number here so it can be accessed
// by all of the following functions.
var number;

// a simple function to save typing document.getElementById all the time
function _e(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
function startf() {
    // Pick a number between 1 and 4
    number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 1);

    // Set the image with id 'test' to have the source 1.png, 2.png etc.
    _e('test').src = number + '.png';
}

function check() {
    // note that == is used for comparison, = is used for assignment
    if (_e('answer').value == number) {
        _e('fa').innerHTML = "TRUE";
    }
    else {
        _e('fa').innerHTML = "False";
    }
}​
```